# How do i uninstall kde packages with unmet dependencies?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, kubuntu, kde, ppa

I recently tried downloading from the software centre when I was greeted with this message:

[image: Metapackage to install all kde telepathy and metapackage to install basic kde must be removed to install a program]

I then tried removing everything kde from ubuntu in the terminal but this is what happens:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
[sudo] password for t: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
 ppa-purge : Depends: aptitude (>= 0.6.6-1ubuntu1.2)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).]
```

Ubuntu software centre gives this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

kde-telepathy-minimal: Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not installed
                       Depends: telepathy-connection-manager but it is a virtual package
                       Depends: telepathy-mission-control-5 (>= 1:5.12) but 1:5.16.3-1ubuntu4 is installed
```

This is not allowing me to install or remove anything!!! I'm not quite advanced at linux so any help will be appreciated. apt-get install -f did not work, by the way. I've even tried bleachbit, to no avail. At this point I just want to get rid of kde completely.

I installed it using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

for removal they list these commands which wouldn't work because of broken packages:

```
 sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
 sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
 sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the needed package and force the installation:

```
apt-get download ppa-purge
sudo dpkg -i --force-all ppa-purge*.deb
```

Purge the PPA and the desktop, as you say in your question:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop
```

Perhaps not necessary but also not a bad idea:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```